# Android View click freezes and not responding for 1 to 2 seconds

Tags: android

I have been creating a music player of my own. And when i click the list item, my view freezes for 1 to 2 seconds, How can i prevent my view from freezing.

I have tried asynctak, yet it hangs, anyway **`ActivityUtil.goPlayHome_Ser(getActivity(), finalI, gridType);`** just calls **Service** only.

I almost finished my music player app, but got struck in this one, need some help. Thank you.

**Function**

```
public static void goPlayHome_Ser(Context context, int position, String gridtype) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MediaService.class);
        intent.setAction(MediaService.ACTION_PLAY_HOMEMAP + "");
        intent.putExtra(Common.BUNDLE_SONG_POSITION, position);
        intent.putExtra(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_LIST_TYPE, gridtype);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
```

**MyRecycler Adapter**

```
private class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private HashMap<String, List<Music>> map;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> headerList;

    public HomeAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, List<Music>> musicList) {
        this.map = musicList;
        this.mContext = context;
        headerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Music>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            headerList.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        /*Collections.sort(headerList, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
            }
        });*/
        if (headerList.remove(Common.HOME_LIST_PLAYLIST)) {
            headerList.add(Common.HOME_LIST_PLAYLIST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adapter_home, null);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final List<Music> musics = map.get(headerList.get(position));
        holder.title.setText(headerList.get(position));
        addGrids(mContext, holder, musics, headerList.get(position));
        holder.gridMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (headerList.get(position)) {
                    case Common.HOME_LIST_ALBUM:
                        PopupUtil.homeAlbumsPopup(getActivity(), view, musics);
                        break;
                    case Common.HOME_LIST_LATEST:
                        //PopupUtil.homeLatestPopup(getActivity(), view, musics);
                        PopupUtil.homeSongsPopup(getActivity(), view, Common.HOME_LIST_LATEST, musics);
                        break;
                    case Common.HOME_LIST_ALL_SONGS:
                        //PopupUtil.homeAllSongsPopup(getActivity(), view, musics);
                        PopupUtil.homeSongsPopup(getActivity(), view, Common.HOME_LIST_ALL_SONGS, musics);
                        break;
                    case Common.HOME_LIST_MOST_PLAYED:
                        PopupUtil.homeMostPlayedPopup(getActivity(), view, musics);
                        break;
                    case Common.HOME_LIST_PLAYLIST:
                        PopupUtil.homePlayListPopup(getActivity(), view, musics);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return headerList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private ImageView gridMore;
        private LinearLayout grids;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_home_grid_title);
            this.gridMore = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_home_grid_more);
            this.grids = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.adapter_home_grid);
        }
    }

    private void addGrids(final Context context, ViewHolder holder, final List<Music> musics, final String gridType) {
        holder.grids.removeAllViews();
        int maxViewCount = musics.size() < 10 ? musics.size() : 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxViewCount; i++) {
            final int position = i;
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_custom_home_grid, null);
            TextView gridTitle, gridArtist;
            ImageView gridThumb;

            gridTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_grid_name);
            gridArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_grid_artist);
            gridThumb = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_grid_thumb);
            switch (gridType) {
                case Common.HOME_LIST_ALBUM:
                    gridTitle.setText(musics.get(i).getAlbum());
                    gridArtist.setText(musics.get(i).getArtist());
                    break;
                case Common.HOME_LIST_ALL_SONGS:
                    gridTitle.setText(musics.get(i).getName());
                    gridArtist.setText(musics.get(i).getArtist());
                    break;
                case Common.HOME_LIST_LATEST:
                    gridTitle.setText(musics.get(i).getName());
                    gridArtist.setText(musics.get(i).getArtist());
                    break;
                case Common.HOME_LIST_MOST_PLAYED:
                    gridTitle.setText(musics.get(i).getName());
                    gridArtist.setText(musics.get(i).getArtist());
                    break;
                case Common.HOME_LIST_PLAYLIST:
                    gridTitle.setText(musics.get(i).getPlaylist_name());
                    gridArtist.setText(musics.get(i).getArtist());
                    break;
            }
            final int finalI = i;
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ActivityUtil.goPlayHome_Ser(getActivity(), finalI, gridType);
                }
            });
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Util.getContentUri(musics.get(i).getAlbum_id()), gridThumb);
            holder.grids.addView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

**MediaService**

```
 public class MediaService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
        private static final String TAG = "MediaService";
        public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "_broadcast_action";
        public static final String BROADCAST_TYPE = "_broadcast_type";

        public static final int ACTION_INITIALIZE = 1000;
        public static final int ACTION_PLAY = 1001;
        public static final int ACTION_PAUSE = 1002;
        public static final int ACTION_TOGGLE = 1003;
        public static final int ACTION_SEEK = 1004;
        public static final int ACTION_PREV = 1006;
        public static final int ACTION_NEXT = 1007;
        public static final int ACTION_NOIFY_SHOW = 1008;
        public static final int ACTION_NOIFY_HIDE = 1009;
        public static final int ACTION_QUEUE = 1010;
        public static final int ACTION_PLAY_NEXT = 1011;
        public static final int ACTION_QUEUE_REMOVE_CURRENT_SONG = 1012;
        public static final int ACTION_QUEUE_CHANGE_SONG = 1013;
        public static final int ACTION_STORAGE_REMOVE_CURRENT_SONG = 1014;
        public static final int ACTION_INIIALIZE_HOMEMAP = 1015;
        public static final int ACTION_PLAY_HOMEMAP = 1016;

        public static final int MUSIC_INITIALIZE_REPLY = 2000;
        public static final int MUSIC_PLAY_REPLY = 2001;
        public static final int MUSIC_PAUSE_REPLY = 2002;
        public static final int MUSIC_SEEK_REPLY = 2003;
        public static final int MUSIC_ERROR_REPLY = 2004;
        public static final int MUSIC_QUEUELIST_REPLY = 2005;
        public static final int MUSIC_HOMEFRAG_REPLY = 2006;

        public static final int FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID = 3000;
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private AudioManager audioManager;
        private Handler handler;
        private Mediaobj mediaobj;
        private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        private NotificationManager notificationManager;
        private HashMap<String, List<Music>> mHomeMap;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            handler = new Handler();
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            int action = Integer.parseInt(intent.getAction());
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand -> " + String.valueOf(action));
            switch (action) {
                case ACTION_INITIALIZE:
                    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Mediaplayer Initializing");
                        initializeMediaPlayer();
                        initializeMediaObj();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Mediaplayer already initialized");
                        initalizeReply();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_PLAY:
                    mediaobj.queueList.clear();
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(Common.BUNDLE_INTENT);
                    List<Music> queues = (List<Music>) bundle.getSerializable(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_LIST_DATA);
                    if (PrefUtil.getShuffleIcon(getApplicationContext()) == R.drawable.ic_action_shuffle) {
                        Collections.shuffle(queues);
                    }
                    mediaobj.queueList = queues;
                    mediaobj.songPosition = 0;
                    mediaobj.music = mediaobj.queueList.get(mediaobj.songPosition);
                    play();
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeQueues();
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addQueues(mediaobj.queueList);
                    break;
                case ACTION_PAUSE:
                    pause();
                    break;
                case ACTION_TOGGLE:
                    togglePlay();
                    break;
                case ACTION_SEEK:
                    int seekPos = intent.getExtras().getInt(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_SEEK_POS);
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekPos);
                    PrefUtil.saveMusicResumePosition(getApplicationContext(), mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    seekReply();
                    break;
                case ACTION_PREV:
                    if (mediaobj.hasPrev) {
                        mediaobj.songPosition--;
                        Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).updateQueueSongFlag(mediaobj.music.get_id(), false);
                        mediaobj.music = mediaobj.queueList.get(mediaobj.songPosition);
                    }
                    play();
                    break;
                case ACTION_NEXT:
                    if (mediaobj.hasNext) {
                        mediaobj.songPosition++;
                        Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).updateQueueSongFlag(mediaobj.music.get_id(), false);
                        mediaobj.music = mediaobj.queueList.get(mediaobj.songPosition);
                        /*if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            play();
                        } else {
                            play();
                            pause();
                        }*/
                        play();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_NOIFY_SHOW:
                    createRemoteNotification(true);
                    break;
                case ACTION_NOIFY_HIDE:
                    createRemoteNotification(false);
                    break;
                case ACTION_QUEUE:
                    if (intent.getSerializableExtra(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_LIST_DATA) != null) {
                        List<Music> musics = (List<Music>) intent.getSerializableExtra(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_LIST_DATA);
                        if (mediaobj != null && mediaobj.queueList != null && musics != null) {
                            mediaobj.queueList.addAll(musics);
                        }
                    }
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeQueues();
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addQueues(mediaobj.queueList);
                    queueReply();
                    break;
                case ACTION_PLAY_NEXT:
                    if (intent.getSerializableExtra(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_LIST_DATA) != null) {
                        List<Music> musics = (List<Music>) intent.getSerializableExtra(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_LIST_DATA);
                        if (mediaobj != null && mediaobj.queueList != null && musics != null) {
                            int songPos = mediaobj.songPosition;
                            for (Music music : musics) {
                                songPos++;
                                mediaobj.queueList.add(mediaobj.songPosition + 1, music);
                            }
                        }
                        queueReply();
                    }
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeQueues();
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addQueues(mediaobj.queueList);
                    break;
                case ACTION_QUEUE_REMOVE_CURRENT_SONG:
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeQueue(String.valueOf(mediaobj.music.get_id()));
                    mediaobj.queueList.remove(mediaobj.songPosition);
                    mediaobj.music = mediaobj.queueList.get(mediaobj.songPosition);
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        play();
                    } else {
                        pause();
                    }
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).updateQueueSongFlag(mediaobj.music.get_id(), true);
                    break;
                case ACTION_QUEUE_CHANGE_SONG:
                    int songPosition = intent.getIntExtra(Common.BUNDLE_SONG_POSITION, mediaobj.songPosition);
                    if (songPosition == mediaobj.songPosition) {
                        togglePlay();
                    } else {
                        mediaobj.songPosition = songPosition;
                        mediaobj.music = mediaobj.queueList.get(mediaobj.songPosition);
                        play();
                    }
                    break;
                case ACTION_STORAGE_REMOVE_CURRENT_SONG:
                    String path = mediaobj.music.getPath();
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeQueue(String.valueOf(mediaobj.music.get_id()));
                    mediaobj.queueList.remove(mediaobj.songPosition);
                    mediaobj.music = mediaobj.queueList.get(mediaobj.songPosition);
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        play();
                    } else {
                        pause();
                    }
                    Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).updateQueueSongFlag(mediaobj.music.get_id(), true);
                    Util.removeMp3FromStorage(path);
                    queueReply();
                    break;
                case ACTION_INIIALIZE_HOMEMAP:
                    if (mHomeMap == null) {
                        mHomeMap = Util.getHomeHash(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    Intent homeMapIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
                    homeMapIntent.putExtra(BROADCAST_TYPE, MUSIC_HOMEFRAG_REPLY);
                    homeMapIntent.putExtra(Common.BUNDLE_HOMEFRAG_MAP, mHomeMap);
                    sendBroadcastMsg(homeMapIntent);
                    break;
                case ACTION_PLAY_HOMEMAP: {
                    if (mHomeMap != null) {
                        int position = intent.getIntExtra(Common.BUNDLE_SONG_POSITION, 0);
                        String gridType = intent.getStringExtra(Common.BUNDLE_MUSIC_LIST_TYPE);
                        if (!TextUtils.equals(gridType, Common.HOME_LIST_PLAYLIST) && !TextUtils.equals(gridType, Common.HOME_LIST_ALBUM)) {
                            List<Music> musicList = mHomeMap.get(gridType);
                            mediaobj.queueList.clear();
                            mediaobj.queueList.addAll(musicList.subList(position, musicList.size() - 1));
                            mediaobj.music = mediaobj.queueList.get(0);
                            mediaobj.songPosition = 0;
                            play();
                            Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeQueues();
                            Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addQueues(mediaobj.queueList);
                        }
                    }
                }
                default: {
                }
            }
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
        }}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something, like perhaps loading a large file or accessing the network, on the main (UI) thread when it should be handled as an AsyncTask (or something similarly backgroundish). It's a common problem, but without seeing your code, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help.

Comment: Show some code snippets. Any long running action on UI Thread will cause this. Try doing your action in a worker thread. Suggesting AsyncTask or your own Thread implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code, I guess that you missing some points:

1. Your `Service` runs in main thread (UI thread). Check [Service Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work

2. Look at your `Database` operations, if I do not misunderstand, you should avoid `Database` interaction in main thread, because I will take time and make your app not responsive.

   `Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).removeQueues();                                           Dbhelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addQueues(mediaobj.queueList);`

Answer (score 0):

You must be working on Main UI thread which blocks/hangs screen. So please use

1. Another [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
2. AsyncTask [AsyncTask Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Or if you use Adapter binding of images.

Then go for [lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) concept. Where images are loaded lazy, meaning your main thread is not blocked.

Comment: my code is not blocked while loading, its blocking while i try to play a song in a service -> ActivityUtil.goPlayHome_Ser(getActivity(), finalI, gridType);